# Getting TF/Count vector with Naive Bayes

Tags: python, naivebayes

I am using Python 3.7 (Windows, 64 bit). Although I can get TF-IDF result but I cant get TF/Count vector after that. Heres the sample code where I get TF-IDF result,

```
DOC, LBL = read_corpus()

# Splits the dataset into training (75%) and test set(25%)
split_point = int(0.75*len(DOC))
trainDoc = DOC[:split_point]
trainClass = LBL[:split_point]
testDoc = DOC[split_point:]
testClass = LBL[split_point:]

# Calling the classifier (use the tf-idf/count feature/vectorizer)
Multinomial_Naive_Bayes(trainDoc, trainClass, testDoc, testClass, tfIdf=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some google search, I can't find any library contains `Multinomial_Naive_Bayes()` method.

You may need edit your question and paste your own method like `Multinomial_Naive_Bayes()` and `read_corpus()` here.

But if you are using **scikit-learn**, you can do this way:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
word_freq_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tfidf_result = transformer.fit_transform(word_freq_matrix)
```